# Icon is pixelate Picture Box

Tags: .net, vb.net

I create a picture box and assign the icon file I got from look up using 
PictureBox1.Image = Icon

The icon is successfully displayed but its kind of pixelate in term of size. When I see the icon in the windows explorer it has better details image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried w DrawIcon function from System.Drawing.Graphic.DrawIcon ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawicon?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yes, it does look better, but not as better as I seen in windows explorer